# GridSearchCV giving " __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fit_params' error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

I am running the following piece of code in a jupyter notebook.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
svc_model = LinearSVC()
svc_params = {'C':[0.01,0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}
grid_svc = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc_model,param_grid=svc_params,cv=5,n_jobs=-1)
GridSearchCV(cv=5, error_score='raise-deprecating',
       estimator=LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True,
                           intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000,
                           multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0),
       fit_params=None, iid='warn', n_jobs=-1,
       param_grid={'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]},
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

Not sure why I am getting this error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20717/2022383170.py in <module>
----> 1 GridSearchCV(cv=5, error_score='raise-deprecating',
      2        estimator=LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True,
      3      intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000,
      4      multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001,
      5      verbose=0),

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fit_params'
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the current version of GridSearchCV does not take an argument called `fit_params`. This might have been a parameter in an earlier version, I am not sure however.

What is this parameter supposed to do?

There also isn't an `iid`, so you might get a similar error if you remove `fit_params`.